# Using remote chrome devtools from Python

Tags: javascript, python, debugging, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to use the remote socket debugging stuff for Chrome devtools ([link](http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/)) from Python.
I'm using code adapted from [here](https://bitbucket.org/brandon/chrome_remote_shell/src/0f361fc11202/chrome_remote_shell/__init__.py).

I've managed to get `ping` and `list_tabs` working.  But I can't figure out how to `evaluate_javascript`.  Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import subprocess
import time, json, socket

from jca.files import my_paths

def request(tool, destination=None, **kw):
  # Send a command via socket to 'DevToolsService' or 'V8Debugger'
  j = json.dumps(kw)
  request = 'Content-Length:%d\r\nTool:%s\r\n' % (len(j), tool)
  if destination:
    request += 'Destination:%s\r\n' % (destination,)
  request += '\r\n%s\r\n' % (j,)
  sock.send(request)
  if kw.get('command', '') not in RESPONSELESS_COMMANDS:
    time.sleep(.1)
    response = sock.recv(30000)
    if response.strip():
      j = response.split('\r\n\r\n', 1)[1]
      return json.loads(j)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  proc = subprocess.Popen('"%s" --remote-shell-port=9222' % my_paths.chrome_exe)
  RESPONSELESS_COMMANDS = ['evaluate_javascript']
  sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  sock.connect(('localhost', 9222))
  sock.send('ChromeDevToolsHandshake\r\n')
  result = sock.recv(1024)
  print 'ping: ', request('DevToolsService', command='ping')
  time.sleep(4)
  print 'list_tabs: ', request('DevToolsService', command='list_tabs')
  request('V8Debugger', command='evaluate_javascript', 
          data='javascript:window.location.reload()')
  sock.close()
  print 'done'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't set a tab_id for destination.  Adding destination=2 to the request call fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry for spam, there's a Java library for this:
http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/

Since you probably chosen Python not at random, you could have it as a reference implementation if running Java code is OK for you. I guess you could check the actual messages sent and received from Java debugger.

Comment: Yeah, I know about the Java library.  (I actually have the same link in my question if you look closely :)  Hadn't thought about looking through the source though.  Guess I'll try that if no one has any better ideas.

Comment: Oops, sorry, now I see. I actually wouldn't recommend reading sources that much -- they are quite complicated (partially due to support of new Chrome protocol "WIP"), looking from debugger how it runs could be more fun :)

Comment: What you could find interesting is http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fplugins%2Forg.chromium.sdk%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fchromium%2Fsdk%2Finternal%2Fv8native%2Fprotocol%2Finput -- it contains Java interfaces that are actually 1:1 protocol definition (for incoming data only).